# Navigating a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

total noob here:

I've got a JSON result coming to a `.on('click')` function which looks like this:

```
{"1411939719-8696.jpeg":true}
```

I want to remove a line in a table, based on where the call came from, but for some reason it's not working:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            var del = $('<button/>')
                .addClass('btn btn-danger')
                .attr('data-type', 'DELETE')
                .attr('data-url', file.deleteUrl)
                .text('DELETE');


               var thumb =  $('<img />', 
                   { id: file.thumbnailUrl+'_ID',
                     src: file.thumbnailUrl, 
                     alt:'MyAlt'}); 

               $('#preview').find('tbody')
                 .append($('<tr>')
                    .append($('<td>').append(thumb))
                    .append($('<td>').append(del))
                 );
                });


          }
    });
```

and the on click function is here:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
    type: $(this).attr("data-type")
}).done(function (result) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // to remove the complete row after delete success
        });
});
```

I need to remove the row that contains the delete button, along with the thumbnail image, but this code isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling the wrong scope.

Maybe this could work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
  //save scope-object to that
  var that = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
    type: $(this).attr("data-type")
  }).done(function (result) {
    $(that).closest("tr").remove(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: if you could let me know how I can create a conditional based on whether the result == true that would be amazing?

Comment: Did i understand you right, that the response is something like this : `{"1411939719-8696.jpeg":true}`?

Comment: yep thats it - the first part is the file name of the file being deleted and is resturned from the server

Comment: At first i would say this is not really a good response, but maybe you can't do anything about it. It should probably look more like `{name: "1411939719-8696.jpeg", deleted: true}`.

Comment: Or do you have a list of multiple objects that were deleted?

Comment: i know - not ideal, but its from a plugin that i dont really want to mess with - at the moment, i'm only gonna allow one at a time, so as long as each one returns true then thats should be fine

Comment: Okay, so you should use the following:

`var response = JSON.parse(result);`

So you create an object from the JSON.

Then you can access the first key of the object:

`var key_name = Object.keys(response)[0]`

And with the name of the key, you can get the value: 

`response[key_name]`